# API - Isolating returned JSON keys and values within indexed objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

Building a web app using a flight data API and, welp, the struggle is real.

My returned array and it's objects look something like this:

```
results:

0:{destination: "YTO", 
departure_date: "2018-01-24", 
return_date: "2018-01-25"
airline: "TS"}

1:{destination: "BOS", 
departure_date: "2018-01-08", 
return_date: "2018-01-11",
airline: "AC"}

2:{destination: "SJU", 
departure_date: "2018-01-31", 
return_date: "2018-02-01", 
airline: "AA"}
```

Before I can dump the results into the DOM to display them to the visitor of the site, I need to run certain returned values through an additional API (long story) so I obviously need to isolate them somehow.

For this example, I'm using destination so my initial thought process is start by to logging out:

```
console.log(response.results[0].destination);
```

Which we know will print the FIRST destination in the FIRST object, since [0] is the index of that object (so in this case in this case we get back YTO).

Since every returned object has an index number, I think I need to loop through them (for each?) to pull the values I need but I'm trying variations of that with no luck.....or for all I know it's something else entirely.

(your two cents goes here)

Comment: Where's the code you've tried so far? What does the raw JSON look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn an `Object`'s keys into an array with the `Object.keys()` method, this will allow you to use the `Array.forEach()` method to loop through an Object's enumerable properties, like so...

```
Object.keys(dataObj).forEach(function(k) {
    var dest = dataObj[k].destination;
    /* ... etc ... */
});
```

Hope that helps.

- More on `Object.keys()` [@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

forEach works for arrays.
try using for loop

```js
for(let key in response.results){
  console.log(response.results[key].destination);
}
```